# Unable to select objects after drawing in FabricJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to free draw rectangle on canvas.

Here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/8u1cqasa/2/).

**Code:**

```
var canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas("canvas2");
var freeDrawing = true;
var divPos = {};
var offset = $("#canvas2").offset();
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    divPos = {
        left : e.pageX - offset.left,
        top : e.pageY - offset.top
    };
});
$('#2').click(function() {

    console.log("Button 2 cilcked");

    // Declaring the variables
    var isMouseDown = false;
    var refRect;

    // Setting the mouse events
    canvas1.on('mouse:down', function(event) {
        // Defining the procedure
        isMouseDown = true;
        // Getting yhe mouse Co-ordinates
        // Creating the rectangle object
        if (freeDrawing) {
            var rect = new fabric.Rect({
                left : divPos.left,
                top : divPos.top,
                width : 0,
                height : 0,
                stroke : 'red',
                strokeWidth : 3,
                fill : ''
            });
            canvas1.add(rect);
            refRect = rect; // **Reference of rectangle object
        }

    });

    canvas1.on('mouse:move', function(event) {
        // Defining the procedure

        if (!isMouseDown) {
            return;
        }
        // Getting yhe mouse Co-ordinates
        if (freeDrawing) {
            var posX = divPos.left;
            var posY = divPos.top;

            refRect.setWidth(Math.abs((posX - refRect.get('left'))));
            refRect.setHeight(Math.abs((posY - refRect.get('top'))));
            canvas1.renderAll();
        }

    });

    canvas1.on('mouse:up', function() {
        // alert("mouse up!");
        isMouseDown = false;
        // freeDrawing=false; // **Disables line drawing
    });
});
```

The problem that I am facing is after drawing a rectangle I am unable to move, resize or at least select the drawn rectangle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Mistake** is you are not adding the object finally when mouse is up. Just change the **mouse:up** event function like this:

```
 canvas1.on('mouse:up', function() {
    // alert("mouse up!");
    canvas1.add(refRect);
    isMouseDown = false;
    // freeDrawing=false; // **Disables line drawing
});
```

It will work fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing the same issue, thanks for the solution provided. If you noticed in this fiddle, duplicate object is creating when moving the shape.

How to solve the issue.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Getting the canvas
 var canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas("canvas2");
    var freeDrawing = true;
    var divPos = {};
    var offset = $("#canvas2").offset();
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        divPos = {
            left: e.pageX - offset.left,
            top: e.pageY - offset.top
        };
    });
    $('#2').click(function(){

        console.log("Button 2 cilcked");

        //Declaring the variables
        var isMouseDown=false;
        var refRect;

        //Setting the mouse events
        canvas1.on('mouse:down',function(event){
            //Defining the procedure
            isMouseDown=true;
            //Getting yhe mouse Co-ordinates
            //Creating the rectangle object
            if(freeDrawing) {
            var rect=new fabric.Rect({
                left:divPos.left,
                top:divPos.top,
                width:0,
                height:0,
                stroke:'red',
                strokeWidth:3,
                fill:''
            });
            canvas1.add(rect);
            refRect=rect;  //**Reference of rectangle object
           }

        });

        canvas1.on('mouse:move', function(event){
            // Defining the procedure

            if(!isMouseDown)
            {
                return;
            }
            //Getting yhe mouse Co-ordinates
            if(freeDrawing) {
                var posX=divPos.left;
                var posY=divPos.top;

                refRect.setWidth(Math.abs((posX-refRect.get('left'))));
                refRect.setHeight(Math.abs((posY-refRect.get('top'))));
                canvas1.renderAll(); 
            }

        });


        canvas1.on('mouse:up',function(){
            //alert("mouse up!");
            canvas1.add(refRect);
            isMouseDown=false;
            //freeDrawing=false;  // **Disables line drawing
        });
    });
});
```

**JS Fiddle Link here.**

http://jsfiddle.net/PrakashS/8u1cqasa/75/

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answer's implementations worked for me. All seem to be un compatible with latest fabric.js versions or have important issues.

So I implemented my own (check the JS in the HTML sources)

https://cancerberosgx.github.io/demos/misc/fabricRectangleFreeDrawing.html?d=9

- supports two modes: one that will create and update a rectangle onmousedown and another that won't and only create the rectangle onmouseup
- doesn't depend on any other library other than fabric.js (no jquery, no react no nothing)
- Doesn't use offsets or event.clientX, etc to track the coordinates. It just uses fabric event.pointer API to compute it. This is safe and compatible since it doesn't depend on the DOM and just on a fabric.js public API
- carefully manages event listeners
  TODO:
- I probably will also add throttle support for mousemove

Thanks